# Is there a built-in typesafe way of localizing a .NET (Core) application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, localization

I've been working in .NET (Framework and Core) for years now, and I'm looking to port a .NET Framework application over to .NET Core.

In this .NET Framework application, we have .resx files with thousands of labels in it, translated in 5 languages. These .resx files have generated C# source code which allows us to statically access them in a type-safe way. The current UI culture is respected when doing so.

When I lookup the documentation for localization in .NET Core ( found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/localization) ), the rules of the game have massively changed:

- You need to inject ILocalizer, IHtmlLocalizer or IViewLocalizer
- Resource files are searched based on where and how you inject these localizers
- Labels are retrieved using magic strings

Am I the only who thinks this is massively and needlessly more complex than what we had in .NET Framework? I can understand where ILocalizer and friends came from, because everything needs to go through dependency injection now. But magic strings? Resx files all over the place?

To be honest, I'm constantly impressed with the underlying machinery of .NET Core, but the localization aspect has left me thoroughly underwhelmed. Is there anyone out there with a solid, productive solution to this issue?
Having type-safe labels is probably my #1 requirement.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: this is the bounty message with better formatting:

I am looking for a solution to localization in C# that

- provides the option to have a single resx file per application (or at the very least, NOT a resx file per controller/view/...)
- provides compile time safety so my application cannot crash/misbehave at runtime because of a typo in one of the resource keys
- has a minimal feedback loop when adding a new label (e.g. add a label to a .resx file, this immediately updates the generated C# code, and now the label is immediately usable in my other C# code without having to build the whole application first)
- is not a hacky workaround

If the only solution to these requirements is the existing .resx workflow, then I would also accept an authoritative answer that draws from official documentation or a statement from a figure with authority inside Microsoft that explicitly mentions resource files with generated C# code as an acceptable, supported alternative to the  ILocalizer story.

Comment: Can you explain "type-safe way"? Do you have a link to older way?

Comment: I'm happily using .resx files for .net Core (and later) Windows Forms applications. If you're targeting the Windows platform and using Windows Forms, you can continue to use resx files as before, even with .Net Core or later.

Comment: @vernou 
With type safe, I mean the C# compiler will tell me if I reference a label that is not present in the resx file. If I change the key, I should get compilation errors.

Old way: add a MyResources.resx file to your solution, set the custom tool to "PublicResXFileCodeGenerator" in the file properties and then just statically use the generated C# code "MyResources.MyLabel" in your code. If you want to translate in French, then you just add a file called MyResources.fr.resx and it will be picked up automatically.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Then my question changes to: is this obsolete? Will Microsoft drop support for this in some future version of .NET, or this is just a poorly documented alternative way of doing things. Because none of the documentation I've found even mentions this option. (if you know of such documentation, please show me!)

Comment: It's not obsolete; it's part of Windows Forms and thus should be supported as long as Windows Forms is supported by the .net Framework (i.e. for the foreseeable future).

Comment: By the way, here's the Microsoft documentation for the old-style resources: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/resources and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/create-resource-files#VSResFiles

Comment: I guess a "key phrase" that I am missing in this story is something written by Microsoft that says "oh and if you want to do localization using classic resource files, that's totally okay too" instead of describing in detail the ILocalizer story.

Comment: But thanks for mentioning those docs, it *is* an indicator they intend to keep on supporting this for the foreseeable future!

Answer (score 1):

You can continue using the old style of creating multi-language applications with .NET Core by having multiple 'resx' files although the preferred way of managing multi-lang resources is by using those interfaces that you mentioned. But I couldn't find a document that mentions that the 'resx' files will be obsolete in the future.

I have created a sample .Net Core web api that uses two separate resource files for providing its strings. it uses a parameter for determining its Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture by this code:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<string> Get(string lang)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(lang);
        return Resource.Test;
    }
```

as you can see in these pictures, I get two different output based on my preferred language.

for 'en':
[image]

for 'fa':
[image]

Comment: Thanks for making a small demo! But I suppose we already knew that .resx files work in .NET Core.

"But I couldn't find a document that mentions that the 'resx' files will be obsolete in the future."

This is the crux of the issue. It is left in the middle whether this is still a recommended pattern for new applications or not. And if is not recommend anymore, I think the "new" flow needs to improve because I feel it is a big step backwards in terms of productivity and refactorability.

Comment: I think it's more a matter of choice. if you choose to work with resx file directly, you have to create the resource file and as you are developing the application, you will have to put every single string that you want to be localized into that file(s). On the other hand, if you choose to go with the new way, you can just wrap up your strings with brackets and make them localized later. every choice has its own drawbacks and advantages. in the official documentation, somehow they say this same thing.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-6.0
Check this part.
"For many developers the new workflow of not having a default language..."

Comment: For the effort, and because there simply may not be a more authoritative answer out there, I've awarded you the bounty. Thanks for replying!

Comment: Thank you! I hope it will be useful for anyone who reads this later